# How to calculate date time on timezone selection in typescript

Tags: typescript

In a dropdown i have different time zones and when user selects time zone from drop down , he should be able to get Date and Time for that time zone.

For example: My local timezone is `(GMT +5:30) Chennai,Kolkata,Mumbai,New Delhi` and Shows Date and Time as 10 Oct 2019 3:03 PM.
Now from dropdown if i select `(GMT +4:00) Port Louis`. It should show me Date and Time as 10 Oct 2019 1:33 PM.

I am trying to achieve this using below code. where bAutodaylightsavingOptionVisible returns true or false for day light saving and `NewTimeZone.Bias` is to get UTC time. But it is not returning me proper date time.

I have tried to convert the local date to UTC using var `dummydate: any = new Date().toUTCString();` which returns string and when i change the same to date object var `UTCDate = new Date(dummydate);` it returns the Date time as per local not the UTC one.

```
var timeInMs: any = new Date().setMinutes(((-1) * (bAutodaylightsavingOptionVisible ? NewTimeZone.Bias - 60 : NewTimeZone.Bias)));
 var d = new Date(timeInMs);
                var ds: any = d.toISOString(); 
                let dt: any = DateTime.UTCtoLocal(ds.toString());
                this.SystemTime = dt;
```

Can please someone help me in to change the local time to particular selected Timezone as Date object